# Transpose column/row, change column name and reset index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DF and I need to:

1. Transpose my columns to rows,
2. Transform these rows to indexes,
3. Set the actual columns as titles for each columns (and not as part of rows)
   How can I do that?

Here is my DF before the transpostion:

[image]

Here is my Df after my failed transposition:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After transposing, use:

> df.columns = df.iloc[0]

to set column headers to the first row.

Then use the 'set_axis()' function to set indices for your rows. An explanation for this function is linked
[here](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-set_axis.php)